# elasticsearch Java API putmapping from JSON file error

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the Elasticsearch Java API to dynamically create mappings.  This is important because I don't want to have to change compiled code to change the mapping.

Almost all of the examples out there are using `XContentBuilder` to do this, but I want to use a JSON string from a file.

Code:

```
client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(indexName)
    .setType("test")
    .setSource(indexMapping)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

File String:

```
{
"test": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "_id": {
        "path": "id"
    },
    "properties": {
        "address": {
            "index_analyzer": "ip4-pattern-analyzer",
            "store": true,
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Error thrown from Elasticsearch `PutMappingRequest.class`:

> failed to generate simplified mapping definition

The same JSON defined using `XContentbuilder` works perfectly.

```
String type = "test";
XContentBuilder jb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().
      startObject().
         startObject(type).
            field("dynamic", "strict").
            startObject("_id").
                 field("path", "id").
            endObject().
            startObject("_all").
                 field("enabled", "true").
            endObject().
            startObject("properties").
                 startObject("address").
                    field("type", "string").
                    field("store", "yes"). 
                    field("index_analyzer", "ip4-pattern-analyzer").
                    startObject("fields").
                        startObject("raw").
                            field("type","string").
                            field("index","not_analyzed").
                        endObject().
                    endObject().
                 endObject().
            endObject().
        endObject().
    endObject();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't ever get it to work using anything other than an XContentBuilder.
I decided to convert the json to a map using Jackson, then map the object using the XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().  I then pass the XContentBuilder directly to the putMapping call.

```
public static XContentBuilder builderFromJson(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    return XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().map(map);
}
```

Comment: Did you find any concrete work around apart from above solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

in applicationContext.xml have something like:

```
<bean id="indexMapping" class="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" factory-method="toString">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:test.json" type="java.io.InputStream" />
</bean>
```

and then you could do

```
   @Autowired
    private String indexMapping;
    .
    .
```

to apply the mapping during index creation try:

```
CreateIndexResponse indexResponse = admin.prepareCreate(indexName).setSource(indexMapping).execute().actionGet();
```

if you want to apply the mapping after then try:

```
PutMappingRequest putRequest = new PutMappingRequest(indexName); 
    putRequest.source(indexMapping); 
    putRequest.type("test"); 
    try {
        PutMappingResponse response = admin.putMapping(putRequest).actionGet(); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Failed to add mapping", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I have to create the mapping at the time the index is created?  The issue is the json string/format is throwing an error.

Comment: yep that is what the above does

Comment: That is not the issue.  Adding the mapping after the index is created works if you use XContentBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I don't think you understand the issue.  Mapping using a string fails with error "failed to generate simplified mapping definition".  Same mapping created using XContentBuilder is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jackson Library for this. This example makes use of elasticsearchTemplate. For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/yourmapping.json");
    JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(new File(url.getFile()));
    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping("index_name", "index_type", tree.toString());
```

and maven dependency:

```
    ...
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```