# Elasticsearch aggregation float type losing precision

Tags: elasticsearch, dynamic, mapping, aggregation

If you use `Elasticsearch 5.5` with Dynamic field mapping
and use double values. These values are getting the float type when I check in the mappings. When you are using an aggregation than the key in the buckets will be losing precision. the Value `0.62` would be something like `0.6200000047683716`.

Code fragment

```
 "aggregations": {
    "float_numbers": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 0.6200000047683716,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the same issue described.
[link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30529)

I am posting this issue because I found an appropriate solution which I not yet have seen but it helped me a lot.

The solution is to make the float a double. This can be achieved with Dynamic templates.

[dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/dynamic-templates.html#dynamic-templates)

[dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/dynamic-field-mapping.html)

Example solution:

Add `dynamic_templates` in index there are no items yet.

```
PUT term-test
{
  "mappings": {
    "demo_typ": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "all_to_double": {
            "match_mapping_type": "double",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Add data

```
POST term-test/demo_typ
{
  "numeric_field": 0.62,
  "long_filed": 44
}
```

Check mapping

```
GET term-test/_mapping
```

Do aggregation

```
GET term-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "float_numbers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "numeric_field"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**In the Java Api you can do the following**

1: First create the index

```
elasticClient.admin()
                .indices()
                .prepareCreate(indexName)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

2: Update the mapping

JSON

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "all_to_double": {
        "match_mapping_type": "double",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Json to XContentBuilder I got the code from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427613/elasticsearch-java-api-putmapping-from-json-file-error)

```java
 public XContentBuilder getXContentBuilderFromJson(final String json) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
            return XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().map(map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Update mapping

```
elasticClient.admin().indices()
.preparePutMapping(indexName)
.setType(yourType)
.setSource(getXContentBuilderFromJson(json))
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

3: Insert data

Answer (score 0):

Numbers lose precision. This is because of how floating-point numbers work: 9.62 can't be expressed as a * 2 ^ b so neither doubles nor floats can represent it accurately.

Because floats and doubles cannot accurately represent a value, it is generally a bad idea to run terms aggregations on them.

As a workaround you can do `Math.round` after you did the aggregation